# Include own/external etcd cluster in kubeadm init

Tags: kubernetes, etcd

I have a running etcd cluster with five members ([Own etcd cluster for Kubernetes](https://serverfault.com/questions/1001778/own-etcd-cluster-for-kubernetes)). How can I include this in the `kubeadm init` command? My idea is that I generate the configuration, edit it manually and then run it. In theory, these are two commands, but I don't know exactly what they are.

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/high-availability/

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a Kind `ClusterConfiguration` in which you need to add the `etcd` config.

```
apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta2
kind: ClusterConfiguration
kubernetesVersion: stable
controlPlaneEndpoint: "LOAD_BALANCER_DNS:LOAD_BALANCER_PORT"
etcd:
    external:
        endpoints:
        - https://ETCD_0_IP:2379
        - https://ETCD_1_IP:2379
        - https://ETCD_2_IP:2379
        caFile: /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt
        certFile: /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.crt
        keyFile: /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver-etcd-client.key
```

Remember to replace following variables with values for your cluster:

> - LOAD_BALANCER_DNS
> - LOAD_BALANCER_PORT
> - ETCD_0_IP
> - ETCD_1_IP
> - ETCD_2_IP

Once done you can init those using `kubeadm init --config kubeadm-config.yaml --upload-certs`

You can also have a look at [Kubernetes The Hard Way](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-the-hard-way).